# pyspark - structured streaming into elastic search

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Im working on a code in which i'm trying to stream data into elastic search using structured streaming by pySpark.

Spark version : 3.0.0
Installed Mode : pip

```
query = inpJoinDF.writeStream \
.outputMode("append") \
.queryName("writing_to_es") \
.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
.option("checkpointLocation", "es_checkpoint/") \
.option("es.resource", "spark_test/doc") \
.option("es.nodes", "localhost") \
.start()
```

Also have tried by adding package & format

```
pyspark --packages org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-hadoop:7.7.1
format("es")
```

Below is the error lines:

> line 328, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
> occurred while calling o57.start. : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> Failed to find data source: org.elasticsearch.spark.sql. Please find
> packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html     at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:674)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:342)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource     at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:648)
> at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)     at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:648)
> at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)     at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:648)
> ... 12 more

Thanks  for helping out!!

Comment: I am receiving function not found when i use packages or jar files..
jar used : elasticsearch-hadoop-7.9.0.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much, i was using spark 3 which is built on scala 2.12, unfortunately elasticsearch-hadoop jar is supported till 2.11 version of scala. I have downgraded my spark version to 2.4.6 which is built on scala 2.11.